# Model - referring to a non-model form-field/paramenter for a validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.3.5

Say I only want to validate the precense of `sub_report_name`  if a checkbox `sub_report_active` is checked.   But, `sub_report_active` is not part of the model.  It's a form field and a parameter but a `check_bok_tag` and not a model field.

Can you refer to a parameter/form_field in the model that is not a field of the model (like below.. .excpet `sub_report_active` in any form I've tried is not recognized in the model).

```
validates_presence_of :sub_report_name, :if=> sub_report_active == 'YES'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you can, but you can easily *make* it a model field without having a corresponding database column by using attr_accessor:

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :sub_report_active
  validates_presence_of :sub_report_name, :if => proc{ |m| m.sub_report_active == 'YES' }
end
```

Comment: Thanks - trying to figure this out.  Proc is returning "#<Proc:0x09936e70@C:/Rails Projects/XYZ/app/models/report.rb:15>" instead of "YES" or "NO"    (I'm on Ruby 1.87 / Rails 2.3.5 if it matters)

Answer (score 0):

This worked (inlucding the need to changed sub_report_active from a check_box_tag to a f.check_box.

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :sub_report_active

  validates_presence_of :sub_report_name, :if => :sub_report_active_yes?, :message => " must be entered if 'Sub Report Active?'' is checked."

  def sub_report_active_yes?
    sub_report_active == 'YES'
  end
End
```